# Why is this bearing calculation so inacurate?

Tags: java, gis, precision, double-precision

Is it even that inaccurate? I re-implented the whole thing with Apfloat arbitrary precision and it made no difference which I should have known to start with!!

```
public static double bearing(LatLng latLng1, LatLng latLng2) {
 double deltaLong = toRadians(latLng2.longitude - latLng1.longitude);

 double lat1 = toRadians(latLng1.latitude);
 double lat2 = toRadians(latLng2.latitude);

 double y = sin(deltaLong) * cos(lat2);
 double x = cos(lat1) * sin(lat2) - sin(lat1) * cos(lat2) * cos(deltaLong);
 double result = toDegrees(atan2(y, x));
 return (result + 360.0) % 360.0;
}

@Test
 public void testBearing() {

  LatLng first = new LatLng(36.0, 174.0);
  LatLng second = new LatLng(36.0, 175.0);
  assertEquals(270.0, LatLng.bearing(second, first), 0.005);
  assertEquals(90.0, LatLng.bearing(first, second), 0.005);
 }
```

The first assertion in the test gives this:

> java.lang.AssertionError:
>   expected:<270.0> but
>   was:<270.29389750911355>

0.29 seems to quite a long way off? Is this the formula i chose to implement?

Comment: Are you using arbitrary-precision trig?

Comment: can you add toRadians and toDegrees?

Comment: Using the java.lang.Math trig function and 
import static java.lang.Math.toDegrees;
import static java.lang.Math.toRadians;

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you've done what you seem to have done and done it correctly you have figured out the bearing of A from B along the shortest route from A to B which, on the surface of the spherical (ish) Earth is the arc of the great circle between A and B, NOT the arc of the line of latitude between A and B.

Mathematica's geodetic functions give the bearings, for your test positions, as `89.7061` and `270.294`.

So, it looks as if (a) your calculation is correct but (b) your navigational skills need polishing up.

Comment: Quite right.  Change the test parameters to 0.0 degrees latitude and the test passes.

Comment: You are right about (b) let me give an example to cement my understanding. If I wanted to walk from Paris (48, -2) to Munich (48, -11) I would not walk due east but at a bearing of 86.652 degrees. This makes sense more if you think about walking from somewhere the uk to greenland, you would not follow a line parallel to a line of latitude (are lines of latitude parallel??).

Comment: Well, you would start walking along that bearing (forget about roads, and obstacles) but you would then constantly have to adjust your bearing as you walked; great-circle routes do not (generally) follow a line of constant bearing (or loxodrome).  But things are starting to get complicated, break out Bowditch.

Answer (score 1):

> java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<270.0> but was:<270.29389750911355>

This 0.29 absolute error represents a relative error of 0.1%.  How is this "a long way off"?

Floats will give 7 significant digits; doubles are good for 16.  Could be the trig functions or the degrees to radians conversion.

Formula looks right, if [this source](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) is to be believed.

If I plug your start and final values into that page, the result that they report is 089°42′22″.  If I subtract your result from 360 and convert to degrees, minutes, and seconds your result is identical to theirs.  Either you're both correct or you're both wrong.

Comment: If this is due to numeric error it is a long way off for such a simple calculation.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure this is due to numeric problems? I must admit, that I don't exactly know what you are trying to calculate, but when you are dealing with angles on a sphere, I'd expect small deviations from what you would expect in euclidian geometry.

Comment: And sometimes large deviations too.